# What is causing this ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join, associations

This follows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628000/rails-whats-wrong-with-this-multiple-join-with-conditions-on-the-associations) prior question, which was answered. I actually discovered I could remove a join from that query, so now the working query is

```
start_cards = DeckCard.find :all, :joins => [:card], :conditions => ["deck_cards.deck_id = ? and cards.start_card = ?", @game.deck.id, true]
```

This appears to work. However, when I try to move these DeckCards into another association, I get the ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord error.

Here's the code

```
for player in @game.players 
  player.tableau = Tableau.new
  start_card = start_cards.pop 
  start_card.draw_pile = false
  player.tableau.deck_cards << start_card  # the error occurs on this line
end
```

and the relevant Models (tableau are the players cards on the table)

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :hand
  has_one :tableau
end

class Tableau < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  has_many :deck_cards
end  

class DeckCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :deck  
end
```

I am doing a similar action just after this code, adding `DeckCards` to the players hand, and that code is working fine. I wondered if I needed `belongs_to :tableau` in the DeckCard Model, but it works fine for the adding to player's hand. I do have a `tableau_id` and `hand_id` columns in the DeckCard table.

I looked up ReadOnlyRecord in the rails api, and it doesn't say much beyond the description.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

**Rails 2.3.3 and lower**

From the [ActiveRecord `CHANGELOG`](https://raw.github.com/rails/rails/3-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG)<sup>(v1.12.0, October 16th, 2005)</sup>:

> Introduce read-only records.  If you call object.readonly! then it will
>   mark the object as read-only and raise
>   ReadOnlyRecord if you call
>   object.save.  object.readonly? reports
>   whether the object is read-only. 
>   Passing :readonly => true to any
>   finder method will mark returned
>   records as read-only.  **The :joins
>   option now implies :readonly, so if
>   you use this option, saving the same
>   record will now fail.**  Use find_by_sql
>   to work around.

Using `find_by_sql` is not really an alternative as it returns raw row/column data, not `ActiveRecords`.  You have two options:

1. Force the instance variable `@readonly` to false in the record (hack)
2. Use `:include => :card` instead of `:join => :card`

**Rails 2.3.4 and above**

Most of the above no longer holds true, after September 10 2012:

- using `Record.find_by_sql` **is** a viable option
- `:readonly => true` is automatically inferred **only** if `:joins` was specified **without** an explicit `:select` **nor** an explicit (or finder-scope-inherited) `:readonly` option (see the implementation of `set_readonly_option!` in `active_record/base.rb` for Rails 2.3.4, or the implementation of `to_a` in `active_record/relation.rb` and of `custom_join_sql` in `active_record/relation/query_methods.rb` for Rails 3.0.0)
- however, `:readonly => true` is always automatically inferred in `has_and_belongs_to_many` if the join table has more than the two foreign keys columns and `:joins` was specified without an explicit `:select` (i.e. user-supplied `:readonly` values are ignored -- see `finding_with_ambiguous_select?` in `active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_many_association.rb`.)
- in conclusion, unless dealing with a special join table and `has_and_belongs_to_many`, then `@aaronrustad`'s answer applies just fine in Rails 2.3.4 and 3.0.0.
- do *not* use `:includes` if you want to achieve an `INNER JOIN` (`:includes` implies a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which is less selective and less efficient than `INNER JOIN`.)

Comment: the :include is helpful in reducing the # of queries done, I didn't know about that; but I tried to fix it by changing the Tableau/Deckcards association to a has_many: through, and now I'm getting a 'could not find association' msg; I may have to post another question for that

Comment: @codeman, yes, the :include will reduce the number of queries *and* will bring the included table into your condition scope (a sort of implicit join without Rails marking your records as read-only, which it does as soon as it sniffs anything SQL-ish in your find, including :join/:select clauses IIRC

Comment: For 'has_many :a, through => :b' to work, the B association must be declared as well, e.g. 'has_many :b; has_many :a, :through => :b', I hope this is your case?

Comment: yes, I didn't have the 'has_many :b' association; once I got that it all worked great - Thanks!

Comment: This might have changed in recent releases, but you can simply add :readonly => false as part of the find method attributes.

Comment: This answer is also applicable if you have a has_and_belongs_to_many association with a custom :join_table specified.

Comment: So helpful - I wish I could mod up more than once! You just saved me an hour or so of going through rails source code and commit messages

Answer (score 171):

Or in Rails 3 you can use the readonly method (replace "..." with your conditions):

```
( Deck.joins(:card) & Card.where('...') ).readonly(false)
```

Comment: Hmmm ... I looked up both of those Railscasts on Asciicasts, and neither mentions the `readonly` function.

Answer (score 45):

This might have changed in recent release of Rails, but the appropriate way to solve this problem is to add **:readonly => false** to the find options.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case, with 2.3.4 at least

Comment: It still works with Rails 3.0.10, here's an example from my own code fetching a scope that has a :join Fundraiser.donatable.readonly(false)

Answer (score 16):

select('*') seems to fix this in Rails 3.2:

```
> Contact.select('*').joins(:slugs).where('slugs.slug' => 'the-slug').first.readonly?
=> false
```

Just to verify, omitting select('*') does produce a readonly record:

```
> Contact.joins(:slugs).where('slugs.slug' => 'the-slug').first.readonly?
=> true
```

Can't say I understand the rationale but at least it's a quick and clean workaround.

Comment: Same thing in Rails 4.  Alternatively you can do 
`select(quoted_table_name + '.*')`

Comment: This may work, but is more complicated than using `readonly(false)`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of find_by_sql, you can specify a :select on the finder and everything's happy again...

`start_cards = DeckCard.find :all, 
  :select => 'deck_cards.*', 
  :joins => [:card], 
  :conditions => ["deck_cards.deck_id = ? and cards.start_card = ?", @game.deck.id, true]`

Answer (score 3):

To deactivate it...

```
module DeactivateImplicitReadonly
  def custom_join_sql(*args)
    result = super
    @implicit_readonly = false
    result
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Relation.send :include, DeactivateImplicitReadonly
```

Comment: Monkey-patching is fragile - very easily broken by new rails versions. Definitely inadvisable given there are other solutions.