# Ruby on Rails: How do I get rid of the ActiveRecord:ReadOnlyRecord error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's happening on teh lp.save line. Which is weird, because I have the same code else where (slightly different though) for re-sorting the link_pages.

the menu bars and link pages are a has and belongs to many relationship

this is in the menu_bar/destroy method

```
 @menu_bar.link_pages.each do |lp|
      lp.sequence = LinkPage::NOT_USED
      lp.save
    end
```

also, rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you loaded link_pages via an ARel :join query, you can probably get rid of the error by changing :join to :include.

A similar question with a more detailed answer was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639171/what-is-causing-this-activerecordreadonlyrecord-error/639844#639844).

Comment: I didn't. @menu_bar is an active record with a habtm relationship with link_pages.

Comment: In that case, if you haven't found any other way of doing it, you could try changing your code to use an ARel query by querying with something like: MenuBar.include(:link_pages).where(:id => params[:id]).first ... (alter to match your scenario)

Comment: My final attempt at helping with an answer - I had this same 'ReadOnlyRecord' error a while ago, and I've looked back in my source code and I've found that I fixed my own issue with the following query (from my source):  VendorStatus.joins(:order).where(:orders => {:code => order_code}).readonly(false).first Again, you will have to alter your own query to work along similar lines, but it may solve your issue. This is Rails 3 code and still works today.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  :readonly => false in your find options.

Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/960903/327786

It works if you use rails 2.3.15 at least.