# How can this code throw a ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, readonly

I have a **Purchase** model which `has_one` **Coupon**.

The **Purchase** model contains this code:

```
def decrement_coupon
  coupon = Coupon.find_by_code(coupon_code, :readonly => false)
  return unless coupon.respond_to?(:uses)
  coupon.uses = coupon.uses - 1
  coupon.save
end
```

But I got this error the other day:

```
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord - ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:245:in `create_or_update'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in `create_or_update'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_save_callbacks'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:in `create_or_update'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:39:in `save'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:222:in `send'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@lyconic/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:222:in `method_missing'
 /var/www/88tactical_production/releases/20110823232510/app/models/purchase.rb:69:in `decrement_coupon'
```

Does `:readonly => false` not guarantee a non-readonly record? Would moving this function to the **Coupon** model make a difference? (I'll probably do that regardless)

Comment: Not an answer, but did you try `Coupon.readonly(false).find_by_code(code)`?  I don't recall seeing the `:readonly` option officially deprecated, but I believe using the scope-like `Model.readonly` method is the "Rails 3 Way"

Comment: @numbers1311407 in my testing there is no difference between the two, and I don't think I'm getting deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This is probably due to joining in other child values through your find_by_code() helper.**

When ActiveRecord uses joins to lookup an object returning additional values, it marks the record read-only.

There's a thorough description of this on this question here:

[What is causing this ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639171/what-is-causing-this-activerecordreadonlyrecord-error)

If this is the case, you can probably fix the issue by turning a your **:joins** into a proper **:include** that populates the ActiveRecord instances without marking them read-only.

Comment: There is indeed a `joins` call in the **Coupon**'s default scope. What is confusing me here is that explicitly passing `:readonly => false` works in the console, but I got the error in production anyway.

Comment: It's an order of operations thing - you're turning read_only off, but then in the processing of ActiveRecord (after taking your default false value) it's setting it to true because you passed a :joins.