# Rails Active Record: modifying and saving the child of an object from the result of joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, rails-activerecord, arel

So, this:

```
p = Person
.joins('join organization o on o.id = organization_id')
.where('o.id' => 1)
.select('person.*')
.first!

p.name = 'hi!'
p.save!
```

works as expected, saving the person's name.
But, how would I do this:

```
p.organization.name = 'bye!'
p.save!
```

I can't figure out the right projection to get the organization fields to map (or if it's possible). I've tried '*' and 'organization.name as "person.organization.name"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for what you're doing to work, you have to set the `autosave` option to true in your `belongs_to :organization` association.

```
belongs_to :organization, autosave: true
```

or just call save on the organization

```
p.organization.name = 'Org Name'
p.organization.save
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare association in your Person class, using 
    belongs_to
    has_one
    has_many
    has_many :through
    has_one :through
or    has_and_belongs_to_many,
 and Rails will do the join by it self and link your both class together.

Let me paste here a section of Rails guide:

With Active Record associations, we can [..] tell Rails that there is a connection between the two models. Here’s the revised code for setting up customers and orders:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

With this change, creating a new order for a particular customer is easier:

```
@order = @customer.orders.create(:order_date => Time.now)
```

I suggest you read the complete guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: No, you misunderstand, I'm talking about this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/639844/2130025