# Update a column to zero from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some weird reason the `new_messages_count` column doesn't update to zero inside the database. I'm doing this from a controller:

```
 @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
 @conversation.update(new_messages_count: 0)
```

The column is set like this:  `t.integer :new_messages_count, default: 0, null: false`

If I do the above inside the rails console then the column gets updated to zero. I have no idea why this is happening, but can someone tell me how to update a column to zero from a controller?

Comment: have you whitelisted field in controller file?

Comment: also add your log while you submit request

Comment: You could always use a debugger and see if `@conversation` fails due to any validation checks. Check the logs too, if you see a Commit message or a Rollback happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ManojMenon. I don't think that I have to whitelist the column inside the controller... because I have the above code inside a show method. So when I visit that show page the column `new_messages_count`  needs to update to zero. Which is not happening! Also now that I'm double checking the console the update action is not apperaing at all.

Comment: `Conversation Update (0.8ms)  UPDATE "conversations" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "conversations"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2021-03-01 10:34:42.686009"], ["id", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:11:in `chat_room'`
   (0.4ms)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kedarnag Mukanahallipatna. I'm getting a commit as you can see above

Comment: Could you try `@conversation.update_column(new_messages_count: 0)` ? If this works, then I think there is some validation that's failing the `@conversation.update`

Comment: How does your `Converstation` model look like?

Answer (score -1):

You may have some validation issues

You can replace `update` by `update_columns` to update your column even if your instance is not valid. (or make sure that your instance is valid)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fabster, I get this error `new_messages_count is marked as readonly`

Comment: @Dev oh your instance is read only. I'm not sure where does this come from but a solution could be : 

```
conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
conversation.instance_variable_set(@readonly, false)
conversation.update(new_messages_count: 0)
```

Comment: getting this now: `nil is not a symbol nor a string`

Comment: ah, forget about my last answer then
maybe try to add this in your model conversation.rb
`def readonly? false end`

Comment: @Dev But then again, I'm not sure why your instance is in a readonly state in a first place. If it does not work I Hope someone else come and can tell us why !

Answer (score -1):

Validation  can block this update
You can check with `update_columns`

```
 @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
 @conversation.update_columns(new_messages_count: 0)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with your code `new_messages_count is marked as readonly`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639171/what-is-causing-this-activerecordreadonlyrecord-error

This may help you